# Can the total mass of a black hole be present at the event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

If the total mass of a black hole were at the event horizon and not at the center of the black hole sphere, would that particles exchange gravity in directions tangential to the radius of the event horizon and try to squezze their position towards the center but which would not in any case affect the radius of the horizon?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? It's very unclear to me. Are you considering a Schw or a Kerr black hole? And what particles are you referring to???

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588429

Comment: Are you thinking of the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) ?

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/123208 I quite like Stan Liou's answer, especially: 
 "Therefore, rather than gravity having a special property that enables it to cross the horizon, in a certain sense gravity *can't* cross the horizon, and it is that very property that forces gravity outside of it to remain the same."

Comment: @PM2Ring If gravity cannot cross the event horizon how is it transmitted from the half of the shell that is the more distant to an attracted body?It have to pass through the part of the volume inside the shell... Is gravity just an inward flux of the so called 'frame'?

Comment: Actually, it's probably better to avoid thinking of gravity as a force in GR. It's just spacetime curvature, so nothing needs to be transmitted. Take a look at this old Usenet Physics FAQ: [How does the gravity get out of a black hole?](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html)